# Как задать position: static для всех элементов внутри <section>

Tags: html, css, layout

Нужно задать для всех классов внутри div class = 'main' значение position: static, но не нам сам div

```
<div class = 'main'>
<section class = '1'></section>
<section class = '2'></section>
<section class = '3'></section>
</div>
```

Не совсем понимаю, применит ли он position на себя или на элементы внутри, или есть способ сделать группу классов. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `.main > section {position: static}`

Comment: position: static это значение по умолчанию, которое будет иметь элемент. Это означает, что если вы не объявите position для элемента в CSS, для него автоматически будет установлено значение static.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main .main__section {
  position: static;
}

/* Применил ко всем section внутри main */
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <section class='main__section'></section>
  <section class='main__section'></section>
  <section class='main__section'></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div class='main'>
    <section class='1'></section>
    <section class='2'></section>
    <section class='3'></section>
 </div>
```

СSS:

```
.main > *{
  position: static;
}
```

Селектор * выбирает все элементы. > говорит о строгой вложенности (вложенности первого уровня). Тем самым мы говорим, что всё, что вложено на первом уровне, будет position: static